# jQuery css function not working across all browsers

Tags: jquery, css

Given this HTML, CSS, and JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/XvqYS/3/

If you run it on Google Chrome it alerts

> 10px

Running it on IE, Safari, or FireFox alerts and empty string. Why?

I'm using IE9, Chrome 18.0.1025.168, FireFox 12.0, Safari 5.0.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Individual properties, such as `margin-left` have to be used.

The basic method to read all properties is: http://jsfiddle.net/XvqYS/8/

```
$(function () {
    var $main = $("#main");
    var margin = [
        $main.css('margin-top'),
        $main.css('margin-right'),
        $main.css('margin-bottom'),
        $main.css('margin-left')
    ].join(' ');
    alert(margin);
});
```

You can tweak it to return a compact [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin#Values), eg. `10px 10px 10px 10px` -> `10px`.

Comment: Funky though. `alert('margin-left')` in IE9 gives 9.99px